# VS code snippet substitution (transform) works with variables not placeholders

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

vs code supposedly is supports substation, i.e., transforms, in user-defined snippets. But its working for me only with (built-in) variables and not placeholders.

See the following snippet:

```
"substitution test" : {
    "prefix" : "abc",
    "body": [
        "${TM_FILENAME}",
        "${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)\\..+$/$1/}",
        "${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)\\..+$/${1:/capitalize}/}",
        "${TM_FILENAME/^([^.]+)\\..+$/${1:/upcase}/}",
        "${2:showMeInAllCapsWhenReferenced}",
        "${2/upcase}"
    ]
}
```

The output of lines 1-4 is as expected:

```
users.actions.ts
users
Users
USERS
```

In line 5 there is a placeholder and I reference it again in  line 6. I want it to show both times, once as I type it, and again in all-caps. So e.g.:

```
fooFoo
FOOFOO
```

But the actual output is

```
showMeInAllCapsWhenReferenced
${2/upcase}
```

Is substitution/transformation of referenced placeholders (as I type) even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last two lines should be:

```
"${2:showMeInAllCapsWhenReferenced}",
"${2/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}"
```

After the final tab the transform is actually applied (so not technically "as you type" the placeholder replacement).

From  [placeholder transforms](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholdertransform):

> The inserted text is matched with the regular expression and the match
>   or matches - depending on the options - are replaced with the
>   specified replacement format text.

So you cannot just use :/upcase for example without the regex capture as you tried to do on line 5 - it can only transform a regex **match**.

Looking at the [grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) section :

> ```
> transform   ::= '/' regex '/' (format | text)+ '/' options 
>
> format   ::= '$' int | '${' int '}'
>
>             | '${' int ':' '/upcase' | '/downcase' | '/capitalize' '}'
>
>             | '${' int ':+' if '}'
>
>             | '${' int ':?' if ':' else '}'
>
>             | '${' int ':-' else '}' | '${' int ':' else '}'
> ```

we see that the :/upcase must follow a regex.  (The "format", of which upcase is one, must follow a "regex" in a "transform".)